# Removing Search Box From Partner/Community Portal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, partner-portal, global-search

I want to remove the search box from the portal. After doing some research I found some useful guidance that this is possible using jquery. I tried to implement the jQuery in the Home Page components but with the new version there is no html check box available. any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000983kIAA ?

Comment: @sfdcfox - Is that option still available given the removal of javascript from the sidebar?

Comment: No, and that's why I asked about a link. Since we now have less control over the UI, I'm pretty sure we cannot remove search these days. Kind of silly, restricting us from turning off a feature.

Answer (score 4):

As of February 2019, some themes in the Community Builder allow you to hide the search component.

`Theme` > `Theme Settings` > `Hide the global search component in community header`

Not all themes allow this. Customer Account Portal is an example of a theme that does allow it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are only 2 ways to do this today. One is to disable chatter for the partner/community profiles (may not be what you want). The other is to create a custom Header with your own HTML and/or image file.
The downside of option 2 is you need to "roll your own" header for everything else you might want, including links/buttons for logout and profile settings, etc.

Here is some sample code that might get you started:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{ margin: 0px; font-family: Arial, Verdana, Sans-Serif; }
.footer{ color:#808080; text-align:right; font-size:.85em; background:  url(https://c.cs0.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer? id=015T0000000XXX&oid=00DT0000000XXX&lastMod=1311775482000) no-repeat; width: 1178px; margin: 0px auto 0px auto; }
.footer-copyright{ line-height:25px; color:#808080; text-indent:15px; padding:0px; margin-bottom:10px; }
.footer {color:#808080;font-size:.7em;}
.footer a{color:#808080; text-decoration:none; }
.footerMarginCorrection{margin-right:20px;}
.tabbedContentTemplate{border-bottom:1px solid #eee; height:33px; clear:both;}
.tabbedItem{margin-left:2px;margin-right:3px;position:relative;height:33px;float:left;overflow:hidden;line-height:33px;background-color:#f7f7f7; color:#666;padding:0px 10px 0px 5px; border-left:1px solid #eee;border-top:1px solid #eee;border-right:1px solid #eee;}
.tabbedItem.active{color:#ea8229 !important; background-color:#fff;}
.gomeTab.active{color:#4e893e !important; background-color:#fff;}
.tabbedContentItem{display: inline;}
.tabbedContentItem p{padding:0px; margin:0px; padding-top:10px; margin:0px 15px 10px 15px;}
.clearAll{clear:both}
.contentBoxWrap, .siloWrap, .apmWrap{ background:url(https://c.cs0.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015T0000000RRRR&oid=00DT0000000RRRR&lastMod=1311790712000) repeat-y; border-top:1px solid #eee; border-bottom:1px solid #eee; margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px }
.contentBox{width:100%;}
.moduleBucket{background-color: White;}
.moduleHeader{width:230px; height:44px; background: url(https://c.cs0.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015T0000000WWWW&oid=00DT0000000WWWW&lastMod=1312762355000) -200px -149px no-repeat; font-size:14px; line-height:36px; color:#494949; margin:0px 0px 5px 0px; padding:0;}
.moduleHeaderText{width:100%; text-indent:3px}
.moduleContent{font-size: 12px ;margin:0;padding: 0px 15px 15px 15px;}
.caseIcon{float:left; width:24px; height:24px;margin:5px 0px 0px 8px; background: url(https://c.cs0.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015T0000000WWW&oid=00DT0000000qqqq&lastMod=1312762355000) -572px -140px no-repeat;}
.licenseIcon{float:left; width:24px; height:24px;margin:5px 0px 0px 8px; background: url(https://c.cs0.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015T0000000ZZZZ&oid=00DT00000005QQQ&lastMod=1312762355000) -380px -236px no-repeat;}
.productIcon{float:left; width:24px; height:24px;margin:5px 0px 0px 8px; background: url(https://c.cs0.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015T00000007OOOO&oid=00DT0000000QQQQ&lastMod=1312762355000) -404px -212px no-repeat;}
.actionColumn { display: none; }
.knowledgeBlock .btn { display: none; }
ul{ line-height: 1.5; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div
style="border-left: 1px solid rgb(207, 207, 207); border-right: 1px solid rgb(207, 207, 207); border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(207, 207, 207); margin: 0px auto; width: 1178px;">
<img
src="https://c.cs15.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015e0000000ZZZ&amp;oid=00De000000AAAA&amp;lastMod=1444763229000"><br>
<a href="/secur/logout.jsp" class="logout">Logout</a>
<h3>Welcome to the Customer Service Center Case Management System</h3>
<br>
<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```